# Testing if two independent variables have the same effect

Tags: testing, regression, stata, categorical-data, economics

I have variables `age` (beginning from `65`) and `female` (`1` if female and `0` if male) in my dataset.

How can I test if being male has the same effect as aging `10` years on the total health expenditure?

I have written something like this, which is probably incorrect:

```
regress totexp age female
test i0.female = age / 10
```

A reproducible example using Stata's `auto` toy dataset is the following:

```
sysuse auto
regress price i.foreign mpg
test i0foreign = mpg / 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along the following lines:

```
regress price i.foreign c.mpg

lincom _b[1.foreign] - (_b[mpg] / 25)
test   _b[1.foreign] = (_b[mpg] / 25)
```

Note that `25` is an arbitrary number to illustrate the idea. You can also divide age by `10` before fitting the regression to put it into decades. In addition, you probably want to multiply rather than divide in your original example if age is measured in years.